# Lifecycle of @After method

Tags: junit

I am trying to gather some information after every test method, and would like to analyze the gathered information after the test class completes. So, I have a private member variable, a list which I would like to add to after every test method completes. However, at the end of the day, the member variable always remains null.

Note: My test class implements Callable interface.

Here is my code snippet:

{

```
private List<String statisticsCollector;

private JUnitCore core = null;

private int x = 0;

public MyLoadTest() {
    this.core = new JUnitCore();
    this.statisticsCollector = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public List<String> call() {
    log.info("Starting a new thread of execution with Thread# -" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    core.run(this.getClass());
    return getStatisticsCollector(); // this is always returing a list of size 0
}

@After
public void gatherSomeStatistics() {
    x = x+1;
    String sb = new String("Currently executing ----" + x);
    log.info("Currently executing ----" + x);
    addToStatisticsCollector(sb);
}

@Test
@FileParameters(value = "classpath:folder/testB.json", mapper = MyMapper.class)
public void testB(MarsTestDefinition testDefinition) {
    runTests(testDefinition);
}

@Test
@FileParameters(value = "classpath:folder/testA.json", mapper = MyMapper.class)
public void testA(MyDefinition testDefinition) {
    runTests(testDefinition);
}

public List<String> getStatisticsCollector() {
    return this.statisticsCollector;
}

public void addToStatisticsCollector(String sb) {
    this.statisticsCollector.add(sb);
}
```

}

So, why is it always getting reset, even though I am appending to the list in my @After annotated method?
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where and how are you accessing getStatisticsCollector()/call() method?
Cause if you are accessing using another object of class then it always blank.

Comment: I am calling this class from another class and expecting to get back a list of String as Future object. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Size zero means You are calling call method with another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code, is it working ?

```
private static List<String> statisticsCollector = new ArrayList<String>();

private JUnitCore core = null;

private int x = 0;

public MyLoadTest() {
    this.core = new JUnitCore();
}

public List<String> getStatisticsCollector() {
    return statisticsCollector;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. This is working. However, isn't it possible to keep statisticsCollector a member variable and still get the same result?